# Add local Printer port with VBS

Tags: vbscript

first of all i'm sorry for my english.

I've one question about windows WMI and how to add a local port to shared printer. I've this script:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set objNewPort = objWMIService.Get _
("Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort").SpawnInstance_
objNewPort.Name = "Ricoh3300C"
objNewPort.Protocol = 2
objNewPort.HostAddress = "XXX.XXX.X.XXX"
objNewPort.PortNumber = "9100"
objNewPort.SNMPEnabled = False
objNewPort.Put_
```

With this i can add a printer with IP address but i want to add a printer in samba server with an address like "\\XXX.XXX.X.XXX\printerColor". I've lost a lot of time in google trying to find an script and all that i've seen is for TCPIP ports. I wan't to do it but in local port.

I've tried to use this script with prnadmin.dll and no luck.

```
function PortAdd(strPort, portType)

    on error resume next

    dim oMaster
    dim oPort
    dim iResult

    set oMaster = CreateObject("PrintMaster.PrintMaster.1")
    set oPort   = CreateObject("Port.Port.1")

    iResult = kErrorFailure

    oPort.PortName = strPort
    oPort.PortType = portType

    oMaster.PortAdd oPort

    if Err = 0 then

        iResult = kErrorSuccess

    else

        wscript.echo "Error: 0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & ". " & Err.Description 

    end if

    PortAdd = iResult

end function
```

I get this error:

```
Error: 0x1A8. Se requiere un objeto
```

in english is like

```
Error: 0x1A8. An object is required
```

How can i fix that error or what script can i use to add a local port?. Thanks in advance.

I forgot to say that i want to do it with normal user without admin access. The first script works fine in that users but is for TCPIP.

Comment: I'm not sure if adding ports can be done with normal user credentials. Please tell on which line the VBS error occurs.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` to see on which line the error occurs.

Comment: i found that the second script give that error because need admin account (i've admin account but i did't run as admin in W7), but the first script add a TCPIP port without problem in Normal account, and i can add a printer with that port without problem but i want to use a Cups printer server to manage all printers and i need to create a local port pointing to server network address. All the problem is because i want to use a custom name for printers and if i add that printers as network printers i get a name like "Ricoh3300C-PS in ServerName", and i want "Ricoh 3300 Color" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [XcvData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564255(v=vs.85).aspx), e.g.

```
    private static void AddPort(string portName)
    {
        var def = new PRINTER_DEFAULTS();

        def.pDatatype = null;
        def.pDevMode = IntPtr.Zero;
        def.DesiredAccess = 1; //Server Access Administrator

        IntPtr hPrinter = IntPtr.Zero;

        int n = OpenPrinter(",XcvMonitor Local Port", ref hPrinter, def);
        if (n == 0)
            throw new Exception("Local Port monitor has not been opened.");

        if (!portName.EndsWith("\0"))
            portName += "\0";

        // .NET strings are formed by 2-byte characters
        var size = (uint) (portName.Length*2);

        IntPtr portPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int) size);
        Marshal.Copy(portName.ToCharArray(), 0, portPtr, portName.Length);

        uint needed, xcvResult;

        XcvData(hPrinter, "AddPort", portPtr, size, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out needed, out xcvResult);

        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(portPtr);
    }

    [DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "XcvDataW", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool XcvData(
        IntPtr hXcv,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDataName,
        IntPtr pInputData,
        uint cbInputData,
        IntPtr pOutputData,
        uint cbOutputData,
        out uint pcbOutputNeeded,
        out uint pwdStatus);
```